# Stop youtube video and replace with image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with embeded youtube video. I need to replace it with the image and when the image is clicked the video starts playing which I have implemented:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function start_video() {
      var iframe = '<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="590" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/nCgQDjiotG0?autoplay=1&amp;rel=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" title="none" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
      document.getElementById("video_player").innerHTML = iframe;
   }
</script>
```

And html:

```
<div id="video_player"><img style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="start_video();" src="fake_image.jpg" alt="Play Video" /></div>
```

But now I have a problem stopping this video by clicking on some div or some other element and replacing video back with image at the same time.

Comment: make video_player innerhtml blank on focusout & insert image again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just give the iframe an id and then remove the iframe and place the image there?

```
function stop_video() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('video_iframe');
    var parent = elem.parentNode;
    parent.removeChild(elem);
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.setAttribute('src','yourImage.jpg');
    parent.appendChild(image);
}
```

I also suggest that you do not set the innerHTML as you did, you should actually deal with objects like this one above.

```
function start_video() {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.setAttribute('title','Youtube video player');
    iframe.setAttribute('width','590');
    iframe.setAttribute('height','360');
    iframe.setAttribute('src','http://www.youtube.com/embed/nCgQDjiotG0?autoplay=1&amp;rel=0&showinfo=0');
    iframe.setAttribute('frameborder','0');
    iframe.setAttribute('allowfullscreen','allowfullscreen');
    document.getElementById('video_player').appendChild(iframe);
}
```

Comment: Could you please give example of the start_video function to deal with objects like you did in stop_video function. Thanks.

Comment: I have added my suggestion to my answer. Thank you for marking it :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you read up on the javascript Youtube [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference) which offers you a lot more control than embedding an iframe into your page

Comment: @user1047517, no, it was meant for whoever did :)

Comment: I also did not downvote, but I guess someone downvoted because this is just overkill in this case, maybe...?